# Node.js export a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

Im a new to writing node.js modules . I am writing a module in thw following manner ,

a.js

```
var fs = require("fs") ;
var util = require("util") ;
var mime = require("mime") ;

module.exports = {
  getDataUri: function (image, callback ) {
    var data = fs.readFileSync(image).toString("base64") ;
    var dataUri =  util.format("data:%s;base64;%s", mime.lookup(image), data) ;
    return callback(dataUri) ;
  }
};
```

b.js

```
var d = require('./a.js') ;

function getDiff(image1, image2, callback) {
  d.getDataUri(image1, function (d1) {
    d.getDataUri(image2, function (d2) {
      if (d1==d2) {
        return callback(true) ;
      }
      else {
        return callback(false) ;
      }
    }) ;
  }) ;
} ;

getDiff('/Users/sarthakmunshi/Desktop/Print/27274510-Geek-head-logo-template-Stock-Vector.jpg ',
'/Users/sarthakmunshi/Desktop/Print/27274510-Geek-head-logo-template-Stock-Vector.jpg ', function(res) {
  console.log(res) ;
}) ;
```

However, when i run b.js i get a weird error ,

```
$ node b.js

    fs.js:438
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/sarthakmunshi/Desktop/Print/27274510-Geek-head-logo-template-Stock-Vector.jpg '
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:289:15)
    at Object.module.exports.getDataUri (/Users/sarthakmunshi/Desktop/Print/all-image/lib/dataUri.js:11:19)
    at getDiff (/Users/sarthakmunshi/Desktop/Print/all-image/lib/comparison.js:4:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sarthakmunshi/Desktop/Print/all-image/lib/comparison.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I am unable to rectify this error . need assistance .

Comment: You don't have any file called comparison.js, you probably meant `node b.js`

Comment: You ran comparison.js in your example, not b.json

Comment: var d = ('./a.js') ; ... should that be var d = **require** ('./a.js') ;

Comment: typo . rectified. but error persists inspite of that .

Comment: is b.js in the current directory - I get that error if I say `node b.js` - and of course, I don't have a b.js - i.e. if you type `dir b.js` you don't get a file not found error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for trouble, I solved this issue by eliminating the space at the end of the path . I feel stupid .